# Card.io : Support for Non-embossed or Printed cards

Tags: card.io

I am trying to integrate card.io sdk in my android app. I was wondering if it supports non-embossed cards as well as it is very important for the kind of app I am working on.

I went through some old posts where it was mentioned that it is not supported yet. I just wanted to know if -

> 1. With latest release 5.2.0, is there any support for printed cards?
> 2. Is there any plan for near future, to support non-embossed cards?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, printed/non-embossed cards are not supported as of [card.io Android SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) 5.2 (nor in [card.io iOS SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK) 5.3).

The feature requires a non-trivial amount of work, but if you're interested in adding the feature, you may be able to look into the source repositories and try to get a few people on GitHub to help contribute. ([Android](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source), common [dmz](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-dmz)).